# ReactJs: Refreshing page after submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use ReactJS, and I have encountered this problem:

I have a simple for with one field. And when I click on the submit button the page complete the code but immediately reload (i don't event have the time to read the console).

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    teamName: '',
    error: null,
};

class SearchingForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            ...INITIAL_STATE,
            results: []
        };
    }

    onSubmit = event => {
        const { teamName } = this.state;
        this.searching(this.state.teamName)
        event.preventDefaul();
    }

    searching(teamName){
       console.log("teamName: ", teamName)
    }

    onChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
        console.log(this.state)
    };

    render() {
        const {
            teamName,
            error
        } = this.state;

        const isInvalid = teamName === '';

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input 
                    name="teamName"
                    value={teamName}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Team Name"
                />
                <button type="submit">Search</button>
              
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Why do I have this behaviour?

Thank you.

Comment: Trying by using return statement at the end of submit function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your code

```
event.preventDefaul();
```

instead of

```
event.preventDefault();
```

and it should be the first line in the onSubmit function.

Answer (score 3):

there is a typo instead of `event.preventDefaul();` it should be
`event.preventDefault()`.
and it used to be in the first line of your method.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to call `event.preventDefault();` at first line of `onsubmit` function.
secondly their is typo error in **preventDefault**
Please use under given code:

```
onSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefaul();
        const { teamName } = this.state;
        this.searching(this.state.teamName);
    }
```